# How to list my app after "Record a video -> Share this with" voice command

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

After record a video with "Record a video" voice command, 
and if you say "Share this with", you see a list of apps via which you can share the video.
I want to attach my app to this list of apps in order to let the user to share the video via my app.

I picked up "SHARE_THIS_WITH" default command and define it as our trigger like below.

```
<trigger command="SHARE_THIS_WITH" />
```

But this simply adds "Share this with" command in the top voice command list shown after initial "ok glass" instead of showing my app after "Record a video -> Share this with" flow.

How can I add my app to the end of "Record a video -> Share this with" flow ? 
And how I can get video data when triggered by this flow ? 
I cannot find any document for this.

Answer (score 1):

With the GDK, there is no direct way to be a share target for media at this time. The best solution at this point is to have your service monitoring for new media that shows up and processing it.

You can setup share contacts under the Mirror API, however. If your processing involves a network, you may wish to investigate this avenue.